# Finding round off error when computing determinant and estimating backward error

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the simple case for $A=\begin{bmatrix} a_{11}\ a_{12}\ a_{13}\\ a_{21}\ a_{22}\ a_{23}\\ a_{31}\ a_{32}\ a_{33}\end{bmatrix}$. The determinant is given by $det(A)=a_{11}a_{22}a_{33}+a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}+a_{13}a_{21}a_{32}-a_{13}a_{22}a_{31}-a_{12}a_{21}a_{33}-a_{11}a_{23}a_{32}$.

Find the round off error in evaluating $det(A)$ and use result to estimate backward error $\delta A$.

So, this is my starting point:

$fl(det(A))=det(A+\delta A)=a_{11}a_{22}a_{33}(1+\delta_1)(1+\delta_1')+a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}(1+\delta_2)(1+\delta_2')+a_{13}a_{21}a_{32}(1+\delta_3)(1+\delta_3')-a_{13}a_{22}a_{31}(1+\delta_4)(1+\delta_4')-a_{12}a_{21}a_{33}(1+\delta_5)(1+\delta_5')-a_{11}a_{23}a_{32}(1+\delta_6)(1+\delta_6')$,

And the reason for two errors is that we multiply twice in each grouping. But now to where I'm confused, how do I take care of the addition operator in my round off model so far, any suggestions?

Comment: Have you seen how to analyze the error for a sum of finitely many terms?

Comment: Is there a wrong way in computing the addition portion? Like adding pairwise all the way through? I'm assuming its very similar to the multiplication

Comment: Were you ultimately able to resolve the problem? Are there any remaining issues?

Answer (score 1):

Error analysis of this type is tedious only when we do not use the correct tool for the job. The standard approach requires the user to name every single rounding error and track how the error terms develops as we complete the basic arithmetic operations. In reality, we have no need for names or exact formulas, but we will settle for an error bound that is so good that we can distinguish the good algorithms from the bad algorithms and identify the inputs that are problematic.

The key ingredient is the $\gamma$-factor used in Higham's textbook "Accuracy and stability of numerical algorithms". By definition we have $$\gamma_n = \frac{nu}{1 -nu}$$ where $u$ is the unit roundoff. It is clear that $$u \leq \gamma_1,$$ but the critical property satisfied by the $\gamma$-factors is the inequality $$\gamma_n + \gamma_n + \gamma_m \gamma_n \leq \gamma_{m+n}$$ where $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $(m+n)u < 1$. The systematic use of $\gamma$-factors allows us to concentrate exclusively on the size of rounding errors. We will write $$r = \langle m \rangle$$ if and only if $$\exists \Theta \in \mathbb{R} \: : (r = 1 + \Theta \: \wedge \: |\Theta| \leq \gamma_m).$$ The following property is critical, namely
$$\Big[r = \langle m \rangle \: \wedge \: s = \langle n \rangle \Big] \quad \Rightarrow \quad rs = \langle m + n \rangle.$$ The standard model for floating point calculations, i.e., $$fl(x) = x(1+\delta), \quad |\delta| \leq u$$ will be weakened to $$\text{fl}(x) = x\langle 1 \rangle.$$

After these preparations we are now ready to address the original question. We will at all times use $\hat{x}$ to denote the computed value of $x$. Let us consider a sum of say $m$ floating point numbers, $x_i$. The standard algorithm has \begin{align} s_1 &= x_1 \\ s_j &= s_{j-1} + x_j. \end{align} It follows immediately that \begin{align} \hat{s}_1 &= x_1 \\ \hat{s}_j &= (\hat{s}_{j-1} + x_j. )\langle 1 \rangle \end{align} because each $x_j$ is a floating point number, so the only rounding errors are due to the additions. In the case of $m=6$ we find that
$$\hat{s}_6 = x_1 \langle 5 \rangle + x_2 \langle 5 \rangle + x_3 \langle 4 \rangle + x_4 \langle 3 \rangle + x_5 \langle 2 \rangle + x_6 \langle 1 \rangle.$$
We mention in passing that this pattern extends to the general case and that the terms that enter the calculation early are likely to make a large contribution to the absolute error. This is the reason why we should always start with the smallest terms when adding, say, positive numbers. Now, in the original problem every $x_j$ is really the computed product of three floating point numbers, say, $a_j, b_j, c_j$. It follows that $$x_j = a_jb_jc_j\langle 2 \rangle.$$ We can now conclude that the computed value $\hat{d}$ of the 3-by-3 determinant $d$ satisfies $$\hat{d} = a_1 b_1 c_1 \langle 7 \rangle + a_2b_2c_2 \langle 7 \rangle + a_3 b_3 c_3 \langle 6 \rangle + a_4 b_4 c_4 \langle 5 \rangle + a_5 b_5 c_5 \langle 4 \rangle + a_6b_6c_6 \langle 3 \rangle$$ assuming that the terms are added from left to right.